# Linq - How can I run each item through a function and then pick the item with the highest function result

Tags: c#, linq

What I want to do is basically

```
var max = things.Select(t => ExpensiveFunc(t)).Max();
var ThingWithMaxResult = things.Where(t => ExpensiveFunc(t) == max).First();
```

But I don't want to have to run the `ExpensiveFunc` twice on each element.

I am learning LINQ so I would like to know the LINQ way of doing this. Otherwise I would normally create an array of things and results, then just pick the array with the highest result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order by the function call (descending) and take the first one:

```
var max = things.OrderByDescending(ExpensiveFunc).First();
```